# Build Server for WPF, SL 4.0 & WP7 projects: Windows Server 2008 or Windows 7?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-7, windows-phone-7, windows-server-2008

I'm looking into setting up a build server that would be running **CC.NET** and build **.NET 4.0** (WPF and Silverlight) and **Windows Phone 7** projects. I'm debating between whether I should choose Windows 7 as an operating system or Windows Server 2008 and trying to collect the pros / cons for each.

Windows 7 Pros:

- Windows Phone 7 SDK is only supported on Win7 / Vista and this needs to be installed to build Windows Phone 7 projects. There's an [unofficial hacky workaround](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115063707/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx) to get it working on Windows Server 2008
- MSBuild 4.0 can be installed without having to install Visual Studio 2010 as it's [included in the Windows 7 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/windows-sdk/ff660764%28v=vs.100%29). I've not found a way to obtain this MSBuild without having to install Visual Studio 2010 on Windows Server 2008 though (the Windows Server 2008 SDK only targets .NET 3.5)
- Based on the above it seems Windows 7 is getting much more attention and the latest tools (even build tools) are first supported on Windows 7 whereas it's often a pain to get them on Windows Server 2008

Windows 2008 pros:

- Currently unaware of ones !

Based on my initial research it seems obvious to me to go with Windows 7, however I feel I might be missing information that would favour Windows Server 2008. Let me know your experience with this: which OS would you suggest choosing for the build server and why?

Comment: We use the same platform for our buildserver as is used for our development environment. Besides, I think you've already answered your own question anyway :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've probably already decided yourself but...

We use a VM running Server2008-R2 as our build machine.

We do this because:

- We don't need all the features of a desktop OS
- We want to make the configuration of the server as simple as possible by turning off all components we don't need on a build server
- We have other VMs running the same OS and so it makes it easier from an administrative point of view.

Hopefully some of those arguments will help in your decision making.
It's a horses for courses issue though.